# What is best way to share masters' geography location to slaves?

Tags: java, android, ios, server

I am designing a structure like below to share master location[image: structure]  .

I might need to develop an API to receive masters location and store into database. Then deliver master location to relevant users. The user could use the web, Android, IOS to get the master location.

So I got some questions as below:

1. Which one is better Socket or HTTP request?
2. Which one is better SQL or NoSQL?
3. Any other thing I need to pay attention to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are Answers to your questions in order :

- `Which one is better Socket or http request?`

For a single request/reply, they are about the same - WebSockets also needs to send HTTP headers when establishing the connection. For back-and-forth communication, especially small messages, WebSockets will be much faster because it doesn't need to transmit headers for every single message - it's a normal TCP connection, and it can use the same connection instead of long polling and then establishing a new one.

- `Which one is better SQL or NoSQL?`

When trying to decide what sort of database to use for your application, it is important to identify what you actually want that database to do.
If you are dealing with large quantities of structured data, then SQL will work well for you. If you are dealing with unstructured data, then noSQL will work better for you.
If you can divide your data into structured and unstructured then you can use both solutions.

Hope this information helps!

Do tell me if anything is unclear in that post, I'll try to clear it up.

Comment: I am wondering if there are some open source code. Somebody told me there are many location store and distribute system existing. I just to know how they structure the application.

Comment: Open sources for what?

Comment: location store and distribute system

Comment: but your question was different and I answered the question according to your answer

Comment: okay I will try to find a open source project for you and will post the link here.